# Updated to Xcode 6.1.1 (AppStore) now Apple ID in preferences "is Not on Any Development Teams"

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Last night I updated my Xcode to the latest build in the AppStore (6.1.1) to just be up to date. I come to try and do some work with it this morning only to discover that my apple id in the preferences just shows

"is Not on Any Development Teams"

I try updating the password, but nothing seems to even force it to use it. I tried restarting Xcode, and rebooting my Mac itself. Nothing works.

I have my provisions and everything managed by Xcode so I'm a little nervous of removing and re-adding the appleId, but I'm at the point now where I guess this should be done. Has anyone done this and can you confirm that your Xcode managed stuff was all fine, after you put the same apple ID back in?

Not very impressed with the update Apple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I tried too many things, but what I believe solved it was to re-add the developer account from XCode/Preferences/Accounts. Remove your current account and re-add it.

I'm not certain this is what fixed it for me but it's worth trying

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a go, with a good network connection. I am just worried about it doing something silly with all my certificates and profiles.. these should be tied to my apple ID so should be ok.. Will find out, and update this post. 

Cheers.

Comment: Yep, as expected this thankfully worked for me! Cheers! All my profiles etc were all safe and sound too!!